# Count Query is giving wrong result with EmbeddedID

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity class like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_STUDENT")
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private StudentId studentId;

    .....
```

The StudentId class is:

```
@Embeddable
public class StudentId implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "STATE", nullable = false)
    private String state;
```

Now I need to find the count of students. I do this:

```
public <T> Long findCountWithFilter(Class<T> clazz, FilterCriteria filterCriteria) {
        Util.checkNotNull("needs a clazz", clazz);
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<T> root = cq.from(clazz);
        cq.select(cb.count(root));

        return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
    }
```

I get wrong results. The count is always 0. Any idea why?